# Magento 2 : Quantity Counter in Product Listing Page

Tags: product, product-list, magento-2.1.3, qty-increment

I have a problem in product listing quantity counter, sometimes it will work and sometimes it will not. I want to create custom JQuery script to enable product counter increment and decrement, But the problem is that, it is a listing page so if I create script others will be affected. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Below attached is screenshot.

[image]

Here's my script that is working in product detail page only.

```
 var $currentQTY=parseInt($('#qty').val());

    $(".qty-inc").click(function(){
        $currentQTY=$currentQTY+1;
        $('#qty').val($currentQTY);
        // console.log($currentQTY);
    });

    $(".qty-dec").click(function(){
        $currentQTY=$currentQTY-1;
        if ($currentQTY<1){
            $currentQTY=0;
        }
        $('#qty').val($currentQTY);
        // console.log($currentQTY);
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue ? if yes, please post your answer

Comment: Hello @ManashviBirla yes I resolved this one in my end.

Comment: can you please post your solution here, so that it would be of help.!

Comment: Hello @ManashviBirla I'm a little bit busy right now in my work. But If I have free time I will post it in here. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ManashviBirla I have now posted the solution of my problem below. please check it. I just added a jquery codes to addtocart.phtml found on Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved my problem.

This is the codes.

[image]

Comment: which file is this ?

Comment: app/design/frontend/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Comment: @ManashviBirla click accept my answer if this answer helped you. so that others can see this and help them if they will encounter a problem like this in the future. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome man! Just sharing what I got. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Others get affected because id of each input box is same.

You can achieve whatever you want by doing following -

You will have to define each input box with different-2 id and give a common class name for each input box (.qty).

For example -

Input boxes id will be like - #qty_1, #qty_2

Class name will be like - .qty

Note - Suffix in the input box id can be the product id of the respective product.

Then put both increment and decrement buttons and input box in the same division (By doing this you can easily find the respective input box). Then you can use the object of clicked element (this) in the function to identify the clicked element.

Assuming that your structure of division is something like following -

```
<div>
<input class="qty" id="qty_1" />
<button class="qty-inc">+</button>
<button class="qty-dec">-</button>
</div>
```

Javascript code Example -

```
$(".qty-inc").click(function() {
   // This will return the quantity of the box which is clicked
  // this is the object of element, which has been clicked
   var currentQTY = parseInt($(this).parent().find(".qty").val());
   // Increasing the quantity
   currentQTY = currentQTY + 1;
   // Setting the quantity of only that element,
   //which has been clicked
   $(this).parent().find(".qty").val(currentQTY);
});
```

You can do the same with .qty-dec , make sure to remove

```
var currentQTY=parseInt($('#qty').val());
```

line as the replacement of that line is included inside the click function.